# Can "in favour of" be used in the context?

Tags: passive-voice, prepositional-phrases

Will it make sense if I say, "Shopping will probably change in favour of delivery services". I would like to say that people will be opting for delivery services rather than go to shops.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On ELL, we only allow one question per question. Your two questions are based on the same example sentence, but are about two separate aspects of English. Please remove one question or this will be closed to new answers. If you also want an answer to the other question, feel free to ask it in a separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "in favour of" is typically used when one thing is being reduced or stopped so that another thing can be increased or started. As a result, both things would usually have to be mentioned.

Now that's exactly what you do when you mention delivery services and going to the shops, but it's *not* so clear in your sentence beginning, "The shopping...". That phrase is not precise enough to refer to actually going to the shops. (Shopping can refer to what people do on Amazon, say. In some places it can even refer to the things we have bought.)

So if you modified your first sentence, it would be clearer. For example:

> Picking up one's own shopping at a store will probably change in favour of using delivery services.

(In practice I also might use "disappear" or "diminish" instead of "change", but the above still works.)

Comment: Thank you for such an informative comment. I really appreciate it :)